# Excel multi word/value search

Tags: excel, performance, filter

I have a master server list, which is an excel file.

One of the columns lists the server name, another column lists the application on that Server, one lists who supports the application, etc..

Secondly, I have a list of 30 servers, which I need to find (or highlight) within the master list, so that I can then determine which apps are associated to these specific servers.

I know I can filter, but there are hundreds of servers on my list, and I'm trying to find a quicker way to pull up all of the rows where one of the 30 servers are listed.

*A DB isn't an option but I wish it were.

Comment: My list has hundreds of servers, so it takes too long to use the filter. Is there a way to bring up the filter, and add multiple words (server names), rather than selecting one by one?

Comment: can you provide instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Take as an example:

[image: SO23939768 example]

The list in ColumnF can be all 30 items, if desired. The result of clicking OK is:

[image: SO23939768 second example]

In first image, $F$8 should be $F$3 in this case.